# Emulating Akamai caching envinronment

Tags: caching, testing, emulation, akamai

I am trying to test some code and view how it would work when it was cached using Akamai. Can anyone recommend a tool or add-on, that would allow me to emulate a page load as it would be when Cached by Akamai?

Answer (score 3):

I used Akamai about a year ago and never found such a tool. I wish I did though, it would have been quite useful.

You *could* use Charles or a tool similar to it, and return the 304 Not Modified HTTP code for whatever assets you want to test as being cached. It's a pretty manual way of doing it, but depending on the scale of your tests it could work.

Answer (score 1):

As var as strictly testing loading a page from cache you could set up [varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/). Just as you can configure the akamai settings on what will cache and what doesn't you can set that up in varnish.

If you're testing for speed then that's another issue as if you test on local that obviously takes out any network lag on it. If you're testing on a relatively local hosting server it would be more accurate as akamai's global network improves page speed by directing the end user to the closest edge server in addition to cache'ing the content. That's not an add, it's just a datum you should be aware of depending on what it is you're trying to emulate.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else needing this, you can fairly easily use nginx as reverse proxy in front of your env. A simple example would be this nginx conf, which allows you to cache responses from an upstream server.  Note that you may need to modify hostfile or host header to meet origin virtualhosting rules.

```
http {

    proxy_cache_path cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=mycache:100m inactive=60m;
    proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    proxy_store_access user:rw group:rw all:r;

    server {

        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {

            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache mycache;

            # proxy to ..
            proxy_pass $scheme://www.yoursite.com;

        }

    }

}
```

You can see this type of thing working here https://github.com/wyvern8/akamai-nginx ..which uses the Akamai property api to automatically configure an nginx proxy with similar rules.